# Reminder feature in iPhone Native Application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my native iPhone Application, I have a requirement to add a reminder to the user's iPhone Device.

Is it possible to implement this feature using current iPhone SDK ?

Or else is there any other way to implement this feature ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by a reminder feature? Do you mean a reminder that works only when the application is open, or a reminder that works even if the application has been closed? In order to do the latter you need to use Push notifications.

Comment: Reminder feature means it works even in the "application closed" status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Push notifications. The steps involved in doing this are too lengthy and involved to list in this answer. Familiarize yourself with [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). You will need a Push notification server or pay a service to handle the Push Notification server for you (such as [iLime](https://www.ilime.com/))

Comment: @Ron Gejman : Thanks for your feedback.. Actually my requirement is like that, I want to add alert to the existing iPhone User's Calender on particular date and time. Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: See this question, in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar