# How to detect iPhone common settings?

Tags: iphone, settings, contacts

I want to detect iPhone's common settings like settings about Mail, Contacts and Calendar.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [simonblog.com](https://www.simonblog.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/settings_import_sim_contacts.jpg))</sub>

I want to detect this Sort Order and Display Order settings for a native contact book application. Is this possible and how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39778/signature-in-question about that unwanted URL in your question. In fact, the whole "Hi, friends" and "Thanks in advance. Ruchir." add nothing to the question either. This is not a forum but a Q&A site. Thanks.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the settings about the Adress Book, you can use the methods ABPersonGetSortOrdering() and  ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() to get respectively the sort order and the display order.
Read the [AdressBook guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [ABPerson class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat).

For mail, you can detect if the device is configured to send email with the class method canSendMail of the [MFMailComposeViewController class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMailComposeViewController/canSendMail). I am not aware of an API that give you more information than that. I doubt Apple would add one (and as a user, I prefer it this way).

For calendar, see this question: [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

And for detecting the locale timezone, it's as simple as `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];`. Again, I invite you to read the [NSTimeZone class reference](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html), to learn what you can do with this object.

Comment: the link you posted for calendar ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar) doesn't say anything on "How to get the selected sync option under Calenders".