# Add data to native iPhone app from our application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar

If I develop an app through which we can choose a date and time and enter a text and that text should be added for the corresponding  date and time of the native I phone calendar. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, should be possible using the EventKit framework (introduced in iOS 4.0). 
`EKEvent` is the class you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    // the selector is available, so we must be on iOS 6 or newer
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (error)
            {
                // display error message here
            }
            else if (!granted)
            {
                // display access denied error message here
            }
            else
            {
                // access granted
                // ***** do the important stuff here *****
            }
        });
    }];
}
else
{
    // this code runs in iOS 4 or iOS 5
    // ***** do the important stuff here *****
}
```