# Where the iPhone store the calendar information?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. Where does the calendar information stored in the iPhone? Is it by using EKEvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calendar is stored in a SQLite3 database at `/var/mobile/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb`. On the simulator, it is at `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb`.

You shouldn't access this database directly.

And yes, EventKit is just using this database.

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I would like to ask that can I use the Event Kit API to add the new event to iPhone calendar? or I should use another method to access and modify the content of the database? Thank you.

Comment: @Mark: See the question [ *Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar* ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)