# Calendar on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, titanium

How can I access the calendar on the iPhone simulator?

I'm using Titanium to make an app, and I've created an event. It should have worked, and now I want to test if it is saved correctly in the calendar.

Can anyone tell me how I can open it?

Thanks

Tjekkles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update for Lion**: To get to the User Library folder, [follow these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/22/access-user-library-folder-in-os-x-lion/).

There doesn't seem to be any way to access the calendar from the simulator, unfortunately.

However, as I found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446587/where-the-iphone-store-the-calendar-information), you can find the SQLLite3 database that the simulator uses and get the data from the calendar there using your mac. If you aren't familiar with SQLLite3 databases, I'd recommend using [SQLite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to look at the file.

**EDIT:** It seems that the location of the Calendar.sqlitedb file depends on the version of the simulator you are using.

When your simulator is open, go to the menu and click Hardware and then mouse over Version. You should see a check mark next to the device version you are using (for me, it was 4.0.2). Now go to `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<that version number>/Library/Calendar/`, and you should be able to find the `Calendar.sqlitedb` file.

Comment: http://menial.co.uk/software/base/ is also a cool mac tool and the free trial should be fine

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, and i'm familiar with the sqlite db.

Comment: I don't seem to have the Calendar folder, only AddressBook and WebKit

Comment: @Tjekkles I looked around a bit and edited my answer to include the solution I found.

Comment: Hi, I got the Calendar.sqlitedb file in Library directory but its not get opened. I'm using SQLite Database Browser Version 2.0b1. Any help to open this file to see my updated events locally on my simulator.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I'm working on iOS6.

Sorry I just read the question, its for Titanium. But I'm working on xCode 4.5.

Comment: that folder now asks for an encryption key..?