# does iPhone simulator calendar store "availability" correctly for an event?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, ekevent, ekeventkit

does iPhone simulator calendar store "availability" correctly for an event?

I've got a test app that populates the iPhone simulator calendar with events, but I'm noting that the availability property seems to be always FREE when reading it back using EKEventKit.

Anyone know if there a known problem here?

Also I note when running the SimpleEKDemo apple sample application, that when it brings up the EKEventKitUI screen to view/edit an event, that I don't see the "availability" field.  Not sure why.  On the actual physical iPhone it appears fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678243/calendar-on-iphone-simulator/6685660#6685660). All simulator calendar information is stored in an sqlite database within the simulator's files.

**EDIT**: I took a look at the structure of the database, and found a value for availability:
[image: SQLite database screenshot].

It looks like the simulator saves this information. Try adding an event in your application and explore the database to see if the availability value is set. Failing that, your best option is to try a real device.

Comment: thanks, but I already know how to successfully integrate with the calendar data using EKEventKit - my problem is just that whilst most fields work (title, location, from date, to date etc) that the availability field doesn't seem to work...I can't see anything about the availability field in your like or how to get it working...any advice?

Comment: Wow - see what u mean - almost like the simulator has a bug around it's ekeventkit implementation of the API.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone simulator does not include a calendar, which might explain why it is not storing any data relating to it.

[If you read this post,](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51727-iphone-simulator-4-0-does-not-have-calendar.html) you will see that the only way to test an app such as yours is on an actual iPhone device.

Comment: The simulator basically just got safari and photos

Comment: it actually does have calendar server side - I've got apps which interact with it & there is an Apple sample code project which uses it - it just doesn't have a deployed Calendar app/UI.  The issue is whilst these apps work fine, the the availability property does NOT seem to work...

Comment: Actually nowadays simulator supports calendar beautifully. It has both "Calendar" and "Reminders" apps preinstalled, and you have at least 4 calendars there - the default "Calendar", Birthdays, U.S. Holidays, and "Siri found in apps" calendar.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way to access the calendar from the simulator, unfortunately.