# Add an event into iCal in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, eventkit

I want to be able to add the date and notes of a doctor's appointment into the calendar in an iPhone app.

The thing is, I do have strings `date` and `notes` of the appointment with the Doctor. I have to add those as an event into iCal in my iPhone application. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EventKit for this.

see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar).