# How to open a custom app from clicking 'view event' of calender reminder

Tags: iphone, icalendar, eventkit, reminders

I have set reminder event in a app using Eventkit framework. I used following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar) for creating reminder in iCal. And also set alarm for the event. Now when alarm is displayed in alert view, while clicking 'View Event' button , nothing happens. How to open the app to show the notes saved when alert view button clicked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that does that. And in action: just put the name of the function. That way, the action will be fired as soon as the alert button is tapped.

Comment: the alert is from ical event. So how to set the action for ical event?

Comment: Oh so you want to set an action for the Calendar alert? You can't. I think by default it fires up the Calendar app.