# I want to add Events to Calendar into my Application

Tags: iphone, xcode, events, calendar

Now am doing my task on adding events to calendar,.Is there any API available for it (or) sample for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow

- [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)