# Adding an event to iPhone’s default calendar from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

Is there any way I can add a reminder to iPhone default calendar?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use *UILocalNotification* to fire alert/notification on a specified date/time. It also supports repeated notifications using the *repeatInterval* property.

Comment: will use this as well, to pop a notification if necessary. thanks for help. 
keep smiling :)