# Is it possible to interact with iOS 5's Reminders app from my app?

Tags: ios, ios5

Is there a way to add, read, or delete reminder items from the new iOS 5 built-in Reminders app?

Comment: great question.  I tried to do this a couple of months ago but failed.  I do hope that Apple opens this up so all apps can post reminders.  (eBay: auction is ending on 10/12 at 5:34pm;  Amazon: Your order will arrive on 10/6...)

Comment: yes this has definitely a lot of potential!

Comment: The chosen answer from Bill Burgess is now obsolete, and Patrick's answer is now the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be all possible with iOS 6! :)

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios6/

At the time of writing this answer was sufficient. To keep it updated here is a tutorial which looks very useful for anyone developing an app which interacts with the native reminders app: [Using iOS 6 Event Kit to Create Date and Location Based Reminders](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders)

Answer (score 3):

The reminders are not on a public API. The "geofences" that are created are visible to some processes (I've seen the fence count in console logs) but in no way accessible to another app. You are only able to register fences to your own app.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible.  There is no public API that is available for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like access to the reminders too, I found a post explaninf adding events to the calendar here ..

[Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

While the Calendar is "ok" for reminders, it makes more sence to use the IOS 5 "Reminders" app, after all SIRI can use it! :p

EDIT: I solved my problem by using Local Notifications....

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return nil;
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = @"Here is your alert!";

// Set the action button title
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

//localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.soundName = @"Bell.aiff";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myCustomMessage.text forKey:@"message"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

This allows me to set notifications which appear like Push Notifications and they are preserved even when the app is restarted.

You can clear them if needed with ..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Plasma

Answer (score -1):

I can help you out with the trigger on arriving on predefined location. here is the code.

1: import CoreLocation.framework

2: in viewController.h file place below code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end
```

3: inviewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController (){
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLRegion *mexicoBoundary;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];



CLLocationCoordinate2D regionCords ;
//19.432608,-99.133208 lat, lon for mexico city
regionCords=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.432608,-99.133208);
//5000 below, is in meters-radius 
mexicoBoundary =
[[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:regionCords
                                       radius:5000.0
                                   identifier:@"mexico_Day"];

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:mexicoBoundary];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"region entered", region.identifier);

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"%@: %@", @"region exited", region.identifier);
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```