# How do I programmatically access reminders?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I may be wrong, but it looks like there is no public API to create/access programmatically reminders in iOS 5. However, there is an app for iPhone that can access them: see [this video](http://vimeo.com/32334502).

The question is: how they do this? Is there any undocumented way to access reminders ? I also looked at the relevant documentation for iCloud, but did not find anything related.

Comment: It seems that there is no public API.

Look here to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653963/is-it-possible-to-interact-with-ios-5s-reminders-app-from-my-app

Answer (score 5):

For `iOS 6.0` there is `Event Kit` `framework` `grants access` to `users’` Reminders.app information.

Refer [ReadingAndWritingReminders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1) link. Hope helpful

Comment: Yes, but this is a new API introduced in iOS 6. The question was referred to iOS 5.

Answer (score 4):

Get reminder list

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"acces to §Reminder granded %i ",granted);
}];
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil];

[store fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
    for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {
            NSLog(@"reminder %@",reminder);

        }
}];
```