# How to add Reminders programmatically in iPhone's Reminder App?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I need to create an app in which user will be able to add Reminders in the Reminder App of iPhone 4. I am able to add the reminders in Calendar app but how can I add them in Reminder App of iPhone?

Thanks-

Comment: Not possible.

See related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653963/is-it-possible-to-interact-with-ios-5s-reminders-app-from-my-app

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Thanks for your response but do you know any where Apple is saying that there is no Public API of Reminders App available for developers? Please let me know if you know this. Thanks!

Comment: I think Apple will not say things they do not support in their API. They will say they support things instead.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor OK, but is there any proof that there is no framework for Reminder App? I mean how can I confirm this and verify this?

Comment: @HarshMehrotra you go to the [Apple Development documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) and read it all. Then you will see that there is no mention of an API for the reminders app.

Comment: @HarshMehrotra How do you usually proof that something does not exist at all?

Comment: @Kai Actually I need to show this to my Client so I want to be 100% sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

A reminders API is coming in iOS 6. Apple have [publicly announced](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios6/) this and if you're a registered developer you can find the details on the iOS 6 beta site.

Answer (score 2):

In IOS 6.0 it is possible to read and write reminders!!!

The Event Kit framework grants access to users’ Calendar.app and Reminders.app information. Although two different apps display users’ calendar and reminder data, the same framework manipulates the data. Similarly, the database that stores this data, called the Calendar database, holds both calendar and reminder information.

[Apple IOS 6.0 Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html)