# Can Android download any type of calendar event? If so, what is the file structure?

Tags: php, android, calendar, download

I have been hunting for ages trying to determine what format of calendar invite/event an Android device can download and incorporate into the system calendar - however I have not been able to locate anything!

By default the device does not support iCal or vCal - and the formats for both of these are well defined and easy to create. For example, this PHP script works perfectly for an iPad or an iPhone - so when you visit the page, the device invites you to add it to your calendar:

```
<?
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "@yourhost.test
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calendar.ics');
echo $ical;
exit;
?>
```

I'm trying to create something similar for Android, but am unable to find any guidance on what file it will happily download natively, **without some third party apps**!

Any ideas or help appreciated!

Thanks,
Kaiesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kudos to Santiago Rebella: [Add Calendar event to Android from web .vcs download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825221/add-calendar-event-to-android-from-web-vcs-download)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=london2012.vcs");
?>
```