# Add to calendar: How to allow Android users to download an .ics file from a website link?

Tags: android

I have tried out four different answers on this site and none of them worked for me, including [Can Android download any type of calendar event? If so, what is the file structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438823/can-android-download-any-type-of-calendar-event-if-so-what-is-the-file-structu?lq=1) and [Add Calendar event to Android from web .vcs download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825221/add-calendar-event-to-android-from-web-vcs-download)

Here is my situation:  I have a link to an .ics file here: http://senseofgravity.com/test/ics.html  It works great when I click on it from my Windows laptop in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  It works great on my iPad in Safari.  However, when I click on it from my Android phone, it just returns the raw data.

Any ideas?  Thank you very much!!

- Nancy

Comment: You need to install an application that can handle ICS?

Comment: Thank you, Stefano, for your question/suggestion.  I have read about third-party apps that make .ics files readable by Androids, but I do not want the users of my website to have to do that, I would like them to be able to click on the link and have it added to their calendar.  I have also read extensively that it simply can't be done, but it seems as though some people here have done it - I just can't replicate it and didn't want to piggy-back on their thread.