# Adding event to calendar app from website?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, calendar

sorry for the relatively vague question - it's more of a "can you do this" because I couldn't find a suitable answer via Googling.

If I see a phone number on a website, I can usually click it and my phone is smart enough to know it's a phone number and brings up the call app/function.

If I have a collection of timestamps to represent a series of event start and ends, can I programatically get it to add the events to the calendar on my phone?

If anyone has any links to tutorials on how this could be achieved then I'd love to see them!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Take a look at [Apple's Event Kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379603/how-to-add-an-event-in-the-device-calendar-using-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is an example of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this led me down a path that helps me find another correct answer here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685279/programmatically-add-event-in-iphone-android-calendar-with-phonegap-jquery-mobil