# Import possibility from iPhone App to native Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, file, import, calendar

So I have this iPhone app, working a lot with my webserver (PHP) and getting data from there, mostly HTML content. In this app you can see a list of events (with date, hour etc). Now my users asked me if they could include it to their native iPhone calendar.

Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Do I need to update my application for that or is it possible to generate a file at the server side which the users simply can download? I kinda hoped I could do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `EventKit` framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html
Like explained here: [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)