# How to import an iPhone Calendar event to my app?

Tags: iphone, events, import, calendar, ekevent

I am looking for some tutorials/guidelines for importing iPhone calendar event(s) to my app.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [Programmatically add custom event in the iphone calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)EventList{

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    // iOS 6 and later
    ReadCalendar = TRUE;

    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted){
            //---- codes here when user allow your app to access theirs' calendar.
            [self performCalendarActivity];
        }else
        {
            //----- codes here when user NOT allow your app to access the calendar.
        }
    }];
}
else {
    //---- codes here for IOS < 6.0.
    [self performCalendarActivity];
}
```

}

```
-(void)performCalendarActivity{
   self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];

    // Get the default calendar from store.
    self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

    eventsList= [[self fetchEventsForToday] mutableCopy];
```

}

```
-(NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {
NSDate *startDate;
    NSDate *endDate;
    startDate = [NSDate date];
    endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];

// Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate
                                                                calendars:calendarArray];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate.
NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

return events;
```

}