# How to add events to iPhone native Calendar from Google Calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-calendar-api, eventkit

I want to add events to native calendar from google's calendar programmatically. I have a program that can fetch events from google calendar and show them in table view.How can i add these events to iphone's native calendar?

Comment: You may take a look at the [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar