# how to add an event to a calendar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

I am letting the user to add events to the calendar in my app.

My question is, can I add a custom field to the view when the user goes to add an event, an example, a 'Birthday' field with a switch or tick box  so they user can record custom status.
and provide notification .
Is it possible to add this?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless they've added something new in the iOS6 beta. (I haven't looked at the calendar changes much)

Pre-iOS 6, you there are no configurable key/value pairs for data, just the pre-existing items Apple already exposes.