# Get all events from iphone calendar without any date constraint

Tags: ios, events

How to get all the events from iphone local calendar without any date constraint.

Comment: you may refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar?rq=1) for getting result.

Comment: This will ask for start date and end date as predicates. But I want to get all the events for all the dates