# Show native iOS calendar in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, calendar

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177284/856388 we can add programmatically event to core calendar in iOS. How to show this native iOS calendar like component on some UIView?

Answer (score 2):

There is no native view for calendar/events, you will have to build your own.

[Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) describers how to access to user calendar and events. Which you can then use in your own app.

The presentation of these item is up to you.