# Adding events using EkEvents in Apple Calendar

Tags: ios, ios7, ekevent

I want to add 200 events in Apple's calendar programmatically. Is there possible to do?
I tried to add..but the process is too slow.
so kindly explain the better way to do.

Comment: [Duplicate] :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar

Comment: I know how to do. but my problem here is to add 200 events. Can i use dispatch method to speedup the process. After finished saving events nothing shown by calendar.