# How to add an event in the device calendar using swift?

Tags: swift, ekevent, ekeventstore

I would be interested in knowing how to add a calendar event in the device, but using swift. I know there are some examples made in Objective-C, but at the moment nothing in swift. Many thanks.

Comment: Swift 2.0 Implementation added :
[HERE ON LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar/34790334#34790334)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Note**: If your app is crashing with `This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.`, you'll need to add `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` to your info.plist. Can follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777416/ekeventstore-access-request-crashes-on-ios-10-messagethe-apps-info-plist-must).

**Swift 5.0 Version**

```
import Foundation
import EventKit

let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
      
// 'EKEntityTypeReminder' or 'EKEntityTypeEvent'

eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
  
  if (granted) && (error == nil) {
      print("granted \(granted)")
      print("error \(error)")
      
      let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
      
      event.title = "Test Title"
      event.startDate = Date()
      event.endDate = Date()
      event.notes = "This is a note"
      event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
      do {
          try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
      } catch let error as NSError {
          print("failed to save event with error : \(error)")
      }
      print("Saved Event")
  }
  else{
  
      print("failed to save event with error : \(error) or access not granted")
  }
}
```

Reference : https://gist.github.com/mchirico/d072c4e38bda61040f91

Comment: for who doesn't know you must import :

import EventKit

to make it work

Comment: it gives error "use of unresolved identifier EKEntityTypeEvent". am I missing something ?

Comment: @Dashrath Use `EKEntityType.Event` (few changes in Swift 2.0) instead

Comment: This is not working in iOS 9 devices. Any idea why? I tried the same code, but in ios9 devices, permission is not asking.

Comment: Please see `Rujoota Shah`'s answer is its not working for you

Comment: You need to add "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description" in info.plist

Answer (score 54):

**Swift 3.0 compatible:**

```
func addEventToCalendar(title: String, description: String?, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            event.title = title
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            event.notes = description
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            do {
                try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
            } catch let e as NSError {
                completion?(false, e)
                return
            }
            completion?(true, nil)
        } else {
            completion?(false, error as NSError?)
        }
    })
}
```

And also import `EventKit`

So you can easily call this method from everywhere:

```
addEventToCalendar(title: "Girlfriend birthday", description: "Remember or die!", startDate: NSDate(), endDate: NSDate())
```

If you prefer, you can put this method inside an utiliy class and define it as 'static'.

Comment: You need to add "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description" in info.plist.

Comment: thanks for @ThetNaingMizo for the info.plist info. I will take it a little further and will add the complete entry on the info.plist
Key      :  Privacy - Calendars Usage Description    
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events

Answer (score 13):

You need to add "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description" to info.plist.
Following code works with latest version of xcode and swift 3.

```
import EventKit
class EventHelper
{
    let appleEventStore = EKEventStore()
    var calendars: [EKCalendar]?
    func generateEvent() {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)

        switch (status)
        {
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
            // This happens on first-run
            requestAccessToCalendar()
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
            // User has access
            print("User has access to calendar")
            self.addAppleEvents()
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
            // We need to help them give us permission
            noPermission()
        }
    }
    func noPermission()
    {
        print("User has to change settings...goto settings to view access")
    }
    func requestAccessToCalendar() {
        appleEventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("User has access to calendar")
                    self.addAppleEvents()
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.noPermission()
                }
            }
        })
    }
    func addAppleEvents()
    {
        let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: appleEventStore)
        event.title = "Test Event"
        event.startDate = NSDate() as Date
        event.endDate = NSDate() as Date
        event.notes = "This is a note"
        event.calendar = appleEventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

        do {
            try appleEventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
            print("events added with dates:")
        } catch let e as NSError {
            print(e.description)
            return
        }   
        print("Saved Event")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to adjust this and eliminate the compiler error mentioned in the comments to the answers above (and a few others), as follows:

```
 var eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

    // 'EKEntityTypeReminder' or 'EKEntityTypeEvent'

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        (granted, error) in

        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
            print("granted \(granted)")
            print("error \(error)")

            var event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

            event.title = "Test Title"
            event.startDate = NSDate()
            event.endDate = NSDate()
            event.notes = "This is a note"
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpan.ThisEvent, error: nil)

            print("Saved Event")
        } 
    })
```

However, I still get the following error at the bottom regarding "EKSpan.ThisEvent" : Incorrect argument label in call (have '*:span:error:', expected '*:span:commit:').

I tried changing "error" to "commit," but it gave me a compiler error saying it expected a Bool instead of nil. It seems like a problem having to do with updates in swift syntax.

Edit: I ended up following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgrY-UJTPRY) and was able to get it to work.

1. First, ask permission to access the calendar and (if that permission is granted) call a function to add the event.

   ```
   var savedEventId : String = ""

   func requestAccessPermission() {
       let eventStore = EKEventStore()

       let startDate = NSDate()
       let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60 * 60) // Ends one hour later

       if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
           eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: {
           granted, error in
               self.createEvent(eventStore, title: "Test Title", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
           })
       } else {
           createEvent(eventStore, title: "Test Title", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
       }
   }
   ```
2. The function that is called in the above code snippet to add the event:

   ```
   func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
       let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
       event.title = title
       event.startDate = startDate
       event.endDate = endDate
       event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
       do {
           try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
           savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier
       } catch {
           print("Error Saving")
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This was really slow on iOS 11.2 Xcode 9.2, so I modified Luca Davanzo's  answer to use queues (works a lot faster):

```
func addEventToCalendar(title: String, description: String?, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { () -> Void in
            let eventStore = EKEventStore()

            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
                if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    event.title = title
                    event.startDate = startDate
                    event.endDate = endDate
                    event.notes = description
                    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    do {
                        try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                    } catch let e as NSError {
                        completion?(false, e)
                        return
                    }
                    completion?(true, nil)
                } else {
                    completion?(false, error as NSError?)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Async/await without completion handlers:

```swift
func addCalendarEvent(eventTitle: String, startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    Task {
        do {
            let eventStore = EKEventStore()
            let requestResult: Bool = try await eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event)
            guard requestResult else {
                debugPrint("Couldn't not create a calendar event. Calendar access denied.")
                return
            }
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            event.title = eventTitle
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Couldn't not create a calendar event. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

same with location and alert

```
   func addEventToCalendar(title: String, description: String?, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, location: String?, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { () -> Void in
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                let alarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -3600.0)
                let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = title
                event.startDate = startDate
                event.endDate = endDate
                event.notes = description
                event.alarms = [alarm]
                event.location = location
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                do {
                    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                } catch let e as NSError {
                    completion?(false, e)
                    print ("\(#file) - \(#function) error: \(e.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                completion?(true, nil)
            } else {
                completion?(false, error as NSError?)
                print ("\(#file) - \(#function) error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation here. Thanks!