# Adding events and calendars with EventKit

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I need to add a event to the users calendar.

So i get all his calendars with:

```
let calendars = store.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent)
        as [EKCalendar]
```

I have a few problems:

1. how do i know to what calendar to add the event
2. I can show the user all his calendars and ask him to choose, but in this list i get [calendar, calendar, birthdays, birthdays]
   i get each calendar twice, so what one do i take?
3. is there a way to add a new calendar for adding events?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add an event with or without Apple's EventKitUI framework?

Comment: I ask because many people know about the EventKit framework, but not the EventKitUI framework which provides a standard modal view controller for adding events

Comment: thanks, but i need to add events that i get from my server and not from the user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to create a new calendar, you should create it and store the id in NSUserDefaults so you can retrieve it next time. I use the following function to fetch the calendar if it exists and create it if it does not:

```
func getCalendar() -> EKCalendar? {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let id = defaults.stringForKey("calendarID") {
        return store.calendarWithIdentifier(id)
    } else {
        var calendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent, eventStore: self.store)

        calendar.title = "My New Calendar"
        calendar.CGColor = UIColor.redColor()
        calendar.source = self.store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source

        var error: NSError?
        self.store.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true, error: &error)

        if error == nil {
            defaults.setObject(calendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "calendarID")
        }

        return calendar
    }
}
```

Now you use this calendar when creating a new event so you can add the event to this calendar:

```
func addEvent() {
    var newEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: self.store)
    newEvent.title = someTitle
    newEvent.location = someLocation
    newEvent.startDate = someStartDate
    newEvent.endDate = someEndDate
    newEvent.notes = someMoreInfo
    newEvent.calendar = getCalendar()

    self.store.saveEvent(newEvent, span: EKSpanThisEvent, commit: true, error: nil)
}
```

Comment: In iOS 8 (and possibly before that) I got the error "Cannot assign a value of type 'UIColor' to a value of type 'CGColor'". Changing to UIColor.redColor().CGColor resolved this for me.

Comment: Great tip, just missing the access requesting, i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28398477/3027848