# EKEventStore access request crashes on iOS 10. Message:The app's Info.plist must contain an NSRemindersUsageDescription key

Tags: ios, ekeventstore

My Code:

```
 EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
 [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder  
            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

The app's Info.plist ***already contain*** an ***NSRemindersUsageDescription*** key and ***NSCalendarsUsageDescription*** key,
but
the code below works fine on iOS 8 and 9, but on iOS 10 it crashes .like:

```
  [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access 
   privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  
   The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key 
   with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ios10`:

You should add `NSRemindersUsageDescription` `access configuration list` in your `Info.plist`:

**Method 1)** if you open your `info.plist` in Xcode, follow below images:

a.click Info.plist

[image: click Info.plist]

b.click the add button

[image: click the add button]

c. set the key `NSRemindersUsageDescription`

[image: set the rescribe name]

d.fill the value  why your app need user’s this permission

[image: fill the value why your app need user’s this permission]

**EDIT**

If you add the `NSRemindersUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist`, then appear the `error`, you add the `NSRemindersUsageDescription` in your `TARGET` like this, have a try:

[image: add describe in target]

**Method 2）** if you open your `info.plist` in source code:

```
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>the describe of your need this permissions </string>
```

Comment: My app's Info.plist already contain an NSRemindersUsageDescription， but on iOS 10 it crashes  .

Comment: @Mr.Wang okay, then the `error` log is your question ` log info` yet?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Xcode 14.3**

The key is now called "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description"