# How to handle calendar and wallet events in WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, icalendar

I currently am trying to handle calendar and wallet events in a `WKWebView`. The events are triggered by buttons that open either .ics or .passkey files - in Safari corresponding windows open up (save calendar event/add to wallet), this does not work in my web view though.

I already tried to make use of

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {}
```

but without success. I get the raw data as URL e.g.:

> data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8;base64,QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KQkVHSU46VkVWRU5UDQpEVFNUQVJUOjIwMjMxMjE1VDA3MDAwMFoNCkRURU5EOjIwMjMxMjE2VDE5MDAwMFoNClNVTU1BUlk6SUFBIE1vYmlsaXR5IDIwMjMNCkxPQ0FUSU9OOkhvY2hicsO8Y2tlbnN0cmHDn2UgNlwsIDgwMzMxIE3DvG5jaGVuXCwgREUNCkVORDpWRVZFTlQNCkVORDpWQ0FMRU5EQVINCg==

How should I handle this?

I could not find much documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to pass information from a webview to your native Swift code. You have a couple options:

1. You can perform a URL redirect with the information (looks like you're already trying this). It would be best to use a set scheme for these redirects such as "myAppName". Then in your decision handler (function in your question) you check the scheme and if it's "myAppName" return `decisionHandler(.cancel)` so the URL is not loaded. You then extract the information from the URL (base64 decode it) and then [create a calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398477/7245977).
2. You can use [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) on the client side to captures messages sent from your website. Parse the data from these messages and then use it to [create a calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398477/7245977). You can find more information about this approach in [this blog post](https://diamantidis.github.io/2020/02/02/two-way-communication-between-ios-wkwebview-and-web-page).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data `URL` (as shown in your question) then you can convert that to its string representation with the following code:

```swift
do {
    // Recreate the URL shown in the question
    let dataURL = URL(string: "data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8;base64,QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KQkVHSU46VkVWRU5UDQpEVFNUQVJUOjIwMjMxMjE1VDA3MDAwMFoNCkRURU5EOjIwMjMxMjE2VDE5MDAwMFoNClNVTU1BUlk6SUFBIE1vYmlsaXR5IDIwMjMNCkxPQ0FUSU9OOkhvY2hicsO8Y2tlbnN0cmHDn2UgNlwsIDgwMzMxIE3DvG5jaGVuXCwgREUNCkVORDpWRVZFTlQNCkVORDpWQ0FMRU5EQVINCg==")!
    // Get the encoded data
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: dataURL)
    // Convert the data into a String
    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    } else {
        print("Bad string data")
    }
} catch {
    print("Bad data URL: \(error)")
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20231215T070000Z
DTEND:20231216T190000Z
SUMMARY:IAA Mobility 2023
LOCATION:Hochbrückenstraße 6\, 80331 München\, DE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This string represents a standard "ics" calendar entry. You can make use of this as you see fit.