# Set specific time for iphone calendar event

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar

Hello I am trying to add calendar events to iphone's calendar, but am unsure how to set a specific date and time. I have looked over the answer from here [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)

so I currently have:

`Store.startDate = [NSDate Date] //this part is what I would like to set a specific year/month/day/hour/minutes at.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/).

There's couple examples as well how to use `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

// date
[comps setDay:10];
[comps setMonth:8];
[comps setYear:2015];

// time
[comps setHour:17];
[comps setMinute:13];
[comps setSecond:21];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: This is great! Can you set set time in the same fashion? For example [comps setHour:11]; [comps setMinute:30];

Answer (score 0):

## Get Current Date

```
 NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    assert(en_US_POSIX != nil);
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
```

## Get Current Time

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitHour  | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:now];
    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
    NSString *am_OR_pm=@"AM";
    if (hour>12){
        hour=hour%12;
        am_OR_pm = @"PM";
    }
    NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
    NSString *strTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d %@", hour, minute ,am_OR_pm];
```