# How to access native calendar by using hybrid technology

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to access native calendar by using hybrid technology?,
For example adding event to calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Cordova plug-in that will call custom native could that you will have to implement, in order to add events to the default Calendar application provided by the OS.

To implement Cordova plug-ins in MobileFirst Platform, see here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/

To programmatically add events, see here for one such example: [Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar)