# Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"

Tags: objective-c, events, calendar

I am trying to save events on the iPhone calendar from my application, I'm using this code :

```
- (void)addReminderWithTitle:(NSString *)title date:(NSString *)date {
    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*30];

      EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
            event.title = @"Event Title";
            event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
            event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
            event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
            NSError *err = nil;
            [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

its not saving any errors, and I'm getting this :
Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"

any help?

Comment: maybe The following links can give you some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar

Comment: i took this code from that link, but still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use your code i add added two properties in info.plist `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` `NSRemindersUsageDescription` 
then I NSLog(@"eventStore=:%@", eventStore); the result is `eventStore=:<EKEventStore: 0x17418ce60>`

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*30];

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted) {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title = @"Event Title";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

    }}];

  NSLog(@"eventStore=:%@", eventStore);
}
```

Comment: @Ali.Jab Under what conditions the alert can appear?

Comment: i need to give the user an alert(reminder) 30 min before the start date

Comment: i think you can  get user's All reminders then add an alert by localNotification

Answer (score 1):

Here is swift code for what you are trying to do. You are requesting access to handle Reminder instead of event, that's why you are getting this error.

```
let store = EKEventStore()

// Request access to calendar first
store.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
            print("calendar allowed")

            // create the event object
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
            event.title = self.activityPara.actName
            event.startDate = self.activityPara.actDate
            event.endDate = self.activityPara.actDate.addingTimeInterval(3600) // 1 hr time
            event.location = self.activityPara.actLocatnStr
            event.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            let controller = EKEventEditViewController()
            controller.event = event
            controller.eventStore = store
            controller.editViewDelegate = self
            self.present(controller, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            print("calendar not allowed")
        }           
    })
```

Also make sure to include Privacy - Calendars Usage Description in your info.plist.