# How to add a hyperlink to an event, in calendar programmatically in iOS without showing actual URL?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekeventkit

I have check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246249/programmatically-add-custom-event-in-the-iphone-calendar) and created an app to simply add event. My requirement is to add a deeplink to an app with some data params, but I do not want to display that in the `URL`. I would rather prefer having a simple text, say "Open this link" added in place of URL to the calendar event in iOS swift. Is that doable? I tried adding HTML `<a>` tag to notes like below, **but it doesn't work**

`eventObj.notes = "Some Notes : <a href ='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Open this link</a>"`

**I would prefer to go without URL shortening.**

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue and it seems like the short answer is No.

The iCal standard DESCRIPTION doesn't support HTML or rich text.

There is an experimental field X-ALT-DESC, which allows you to add HTML to calendar events. And in Outlook you can use it, but as for iOS 13.2 it is not natively supported by Apple.

EventKit API is also doesn't have a way to add the HTML or rich text.
So, the only way you have your links highlighted is by old-plain url detection.

Hence, unfortunately you will have to add your URLs as-is.